# $p(s_1,...,s_n)$ is injective iff each $S_i$ is infinite

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to prove that the following function is injective iff each $S_i$ is infinite.

$\mathbb{R}$[$x_1,...,x_n$] is the ring of real polynomials. $S_1,...S_n$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $S = S_1 \times ... \times S_n$, then:

$\pi : \mathbb{R}$[$x_1,...,x_n$] $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{R}^S$

$\pi (p(x_1,...,x_n))$  := $p(s_1,...,s_n)$

So, here is what I have. I know that for $\pi$ to be injective $ker \hspace{0.2em}\pi$ = $\vec{0}$, therefore:

$p(s_1,...,s_n)$ = $0$, means that $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ = $0$

Since $p(x_1,...,x_n)$ can be written as:

$\sum (a_{i_1},...,a_{i_n})(x_1^{i_1},...,x_n^{i_n})$ where $a_{i_1},...,a_{i_n} \geq 0$ and the sum is finite.

So, I need to somehow show that $(a_{i_1},...,a_{i_n})$ = $0$ for every $i_1,...,i_n$ in order for $\pi$ to be injective.

Does this makes sense? If so, how would one go about proving the condition for $(a_{i_1},...,a_{i_n})$?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct form of a polynomial is

$$ \sum_{(i_1,\dots,i_n) \in \mathbf{N}^n} a_{i_1,\dots,i_n} x_1^{i_1} \cdots x_n^{i_n}. $$

Let's take $n = 1$ as an example. If $S \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ is finite, then I can find a polynomial $f$ whose set of zeroes is exactly $S$. That is, $f(x) = \prod_{s \in S} (x - s)$. So $f \in \ker \pi$.

Conversely, if $S$ is infinite, check that $\pi(f) = 0$ means that $f$ has infinitely many zeroes and that this means that $f = 0$.

Now think about how to extend this to multiple variables. For the second part, try writing your polynomials as

$$ p(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \sum_{i} g_i(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}) x_n^i $$

and use induction.

Comment: $\pi$ *is* a linear map.

Comment: @Berci I take it back, you're right. Give me a minute to correct.

Comment: So I could simply say that, for example $p(x_1,...,x_n) = \sum a_i x_n^i$ where $a_i = g_i(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$? And then, apply the same concept as with $n=1$, and then prove the same thing for $n-1$? Where $p(x_1,...,x_{n-1}) = \sum b_i x_{n-1}^i$ and $b_i = g_i(x_1,...,x_{n-2})$.

Comment: That's the rough idea, the details might require some thought. @mecha_physics